# python save calculated value created with try except in function to list

Tags: python, function

Hi I have these nested dictionaries and lists as my data. Here is an abstract of two matches.

```
  my_stats = [
     {'_id': 'GLEvHIL2020031419A', 'stats': 
     {'data': [
     {'area': 'B1', 'key': 'Lineouts', 'possession': 'against', 'second': 7, 'endSecond': 27, 
     'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:43', 'Lineout Presentation': 'Scrappy', 'Lineout Errors': 'Lost'},
     {'area': 'D2', 'key': 'Lineouts', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 344, 'endSecond': 383, 'time': 
      '2020-03-14T12:53:43', 'Lineout Presentation': 'Goodball', 'Lineout Errors': 'Lost'},
     {'area': 'A1', 'key': 'Lineouts', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 354, 'endSecond': 358, 'time': 
      '2020-03-14T12:56:43', 'Lineout Errors': 'Lost'}]}},
     {'_id': 'HJSvMON2020031419A', 'stats': 
     {'data': 
     [{'area': 'C1', 'key': 'Kick Off', 'possession': 'against', 'second': 0, 'endSecond': 6, 'time': 
     '2020-03-14T12:00:06', 'Kick Off Fielded': 'Unsuccessful'},
     {'key': 'Passive Tackle', 'possession': 'against', 'second': 9, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:09', 
     'value': 9, 'subMetric': 3, 'rtp': []}, 
     {'area': 'D1', 'key': 'Rucks', 'possession': 'against', 'second': 9, 'endSecond': 19, 'time': '2020- 
      03-14T12:00:19'}, 
     {'area': 'D1', 'key': 'Lineouts', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 33, 'endSecond': 45, 'time': '2020- 
     03-14T12:00:45', 'Lineout Formations': '5 Man', 'Lineout Area Of Throw': 'Front', 'Lineout 
     Contested': 'Contested', 'Lineout Presentation': 'Scrappy', 'Lineout Errors': 'Lost', 'Maul Meters': 
     '5'}, 
     {'key': 'Neutral Tackle', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 45, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:45', 'value': 
     1, 'subMetric': 2, 'rtp': [{'key': 'Defender in Position', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 49, 
    'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:49', 'value': 1, 'subMetric': None}]},
     {'area': 'D1', 'key': 'Rucks', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 47, 'endSecond': 50, 'time': '2020-03- 
     14T12:00:50'}, 
     {'key': 'Defender in Position', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 49, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:49', 
     'value': 1, 'subMetric': None, 'rtp': []}, 
     {'key': 'Passive Tackle', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 51, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:51', 'value':       
     7, 'subMetric': 3, 'rtp': [{'key': 'Defender in Position', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 53, 
     'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:53', 'value': 7, 'subMetric': None}]}, 
     {'key': 'Tackle Assist', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 52, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:52', 'value': 
     8, 'subMetric': None, 'rtp': [{'key': 'Defender in Position', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 53, 
     'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:53', 'value': 8, 'subMetric': None}]}, 
     {'key': 'Defender in Position', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 53, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:53', 
     'value': 8, 'subMetric': None, 'rtp': []}]}}]
```

I need to write a function where I calculate the Lineouts won per match and save the game name (_id) and the amount of Goodball, Scrappy and Drive lineouts per match.

```
 Lineouts = []
    Games = []
    def Our_Lineouts_Won():
            global Lineouts
            Lineouts = (0)
            
            for l in my_stats:
                t=(l['stats']['data'])
                print(l['_id'])
                Games.append(str(l['_id']))
                
                for i in t:
                     
                     try:
                         if ((i['key']) == 'Lineouts' and (i['possession'])== 'for'and ((i[('Lineout 
                         Presentation')])==  'Off the Top'  or 'Scrappy' or  'Drive'  )):
                                       
                            Lineouts += 1 
                            
                     except KeyError:
                        pass  
        
    Our_Lineouts_Won()
```

My desired outcome would be a dictionary where the key is the _id and the value is the calculated Our_Lineouts_won().

I have tried appending the Lineouts to a list.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I managed to answer my question. I created a dictionary lpg... short for lineouts per game. Then I appended all the _id to a list Games.

After that I went with try and except, to stop the code from breaking if no Lineout presentation was captured.

each lineout that met the criteria was added per game and saved under the variable L1.

And then I updated my empty dictionary with

lpg.update({games:L1})

an as you can see I created the dataframe off the dictionary with df = pd.DataFrame(list (lpg.items())).

```
Lineouts = []
Games = []
lpg = {}
def Our_Lineouts_Won():
        global Lineouts
        global lpg
        Lineouts = (0)
        lpg = {}
        for l in my_stats:
            t=(l['stats']['data'])
            games = (l['_id'])
            Games.append(str(l['_id']))
            #print (games)
            
            for i in t:
                 
                 try:
                     if ((i['key']) == 'Lineouts' and (i['possession'])== 'for'and ((i[('Lineout Presentation')])==  'Off the Top'  or 'Scrappy' or  'Drive'  )):
            #if ((i['key']) == 'Lineouts' and (i['possession'])== 'for'and ((i[('Lineout Presentation')])==  'Off the Top'  or (i[('Lineout Presentation')])==  'Scrappy' or (i[('Lineout Presentation')])==  'Drive'  )):
                        
                         Lineouts += 1
                        
                 except KeyError:
                    pass  
            
            L1=(str(Lineouts))
            
            lpg.update({games:L1})
            
            
            
        
            
            Lineouts = (0)
               
            
            
        #print (lpg)   
             
       
Our_Lineouts_Won()
```